# element.insertAdjacentHTML not adding html to DOM

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11

Below code:

```
export const showAddedFilesNames = ({
  baseIdentifiers: identifiers,
  inputFileElement,
  container: elementContainer,
  dragContainerDiv,
}) => {
  const paragraphID = identifiers.fileNameParagraphID.slice(1);
  let markup = ``;
  inputFileElement.files.forEach((file, index) => {
    markup += `<p data-index="${index}" id="${paragraphID}"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle mr-2"></i>${
      file.name
    }</p>`;
  });
  elementContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', markup);
  dragContainerDiv.classList.remove('dragover');
  inputFileElement.value = null;
};
```

Is not adding markup to DOM by insertAdjacentHTML on ie11 (works perfectly on other browsers). When I change the first parameter in insertAdjacentHTML from 'beforeEnd' to 'afterEnd' somehow it works. Also when trying to add static html instead of markup variable then it also works.

The markup is a valid HTML code, I checked it in by console logging and here is an example of what is logged from markup variable:

```html
<p data-index="0" id="filename"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle mr-2"></i>278893-dfd773dbb6347ccdd47b76138b291193.jpg</p>
```

If I will try to add below markup to markup variable just a static text, then it also works... this is very strange to me.

I'm using webpack together with babel to create bundle and polyfills to have it working on ie.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: @Barmar unfortunately not, no errors.

Comment: There's no way it can make a difference whether you're inserting static HTML or HTML from a variable if they really contain the same thing. There must be some difference that you didn't notice.

Comment: I made a test with the sample code and looks like it is working as expected in IE 11. https://textuploader.com/1duej I suggest you to run it directly in IE 11 to check the result. I also suggest you to check your transpiled code to see whether there is any unexpected or incorrect change may help to find the cause for the issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT, The problem was in this line of code:

```javascript
inputFileElement.value = null;
```
IE11 because of this line would fire twice the change event to input and the second time it would add an empty line to the place where my variable markup should be located. In chrome or firefox the event would fire only once. So I got rid of that line of code, and now everything works even in IE11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in this line of code: javascript inputFileElement.value = null; IE11 because of this line would fire twice the change event to input and the second time it would add an empty line to the place where my variable markup should be located. In chrome or firefox the event would fire only once. So I got rid of that line of code, and now everything works even in IE11.